# Tags not appearing in "Add New Post" Page

Tags: wordpress, tags

I'm working on a mag website. I'm using `Tags` to group some content.
For this I have added all the required tags from the **Tags** section under **Posts**.
But When I go to `Posts -> Add New`, the Tags panel displays nothing.

[image]

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-get_the_tag-to-label-post-titles

Answer (score 0):

As you start typing in the text field and wait for 1 or 2 seconds, for example type 'a' and it will show tags starting with 'a' as dropdown list if there is any match in existing tags with your typed alphabet or word. After that you can select existing tags from the dropdown list.